# System.BadImageFormatException nothing seems to work

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio, wcf

I have a problem running my WCF code in Viusal Studio named, System.BadImageFormatException, which is thrown when try to access "Oracle.DataAcces.dll". It's fine i have researched a lot and found that i have to target x86 platform in my project. But now the fun part: if i target platform x86 i go System.BadImageFormatException again thrown from "WcfServiceLibrary1\WcfServiceLibrary1\bin\Debug\WcfServiceLibrary1.dll", which is "<<"my_solution">>\<<"my_project">>\<<"bin">>\<<"debug">>.

I have tried :

- change target platform to 64/x86/any
- Tools => Options => Project and Solution => Web Projects => uncheck/check the "Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects"
- Create new WCF service library ( copy paste the code)
- remove/add Oracle.DataAcces ( 2.112.1.0 / 4.112.3.0 )

None of the mentioned worked or resulted in some other output than the original exception.

I'm on a 64bit Windows OS, VS2017 64bit, Oracle.DataAcces x86.

Days of research without result, so I'm really out of tips.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the exception message?

Comment: Sounds like you need to change _all_ of your projects to 32-bit.

Comment: Does this help https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/InstallODP.htm#ODPNT150? The ODP library you are using seems to have managed and unmanaged components. The managed stuff should not care about the bitness, whereas the unmanaged bit does.

Comment: Don't know what the problem was. Re-created the service from scratch ( also the referenced objects ) and now it's working. I suppose that one or more of the referenced files used something with 64bit bitness. Resolution: always write your the things yourself.